# Is there a way to dynamically load input file (.osm.pbf) to docker image of OSRM?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, osrm

I run a docker image of OSRM on my machine. I'd like to dynamically load osm data that i take from OverpassAPI.

Is there a way to do so without restarting OSRM every time?

I tried using [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/) data, but I'd like to use a way smaller area.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the answer to your question is 'no'. There is no way to dynamically append say new edges/nodes to a network, at least according to a [discussion thread on the osrm-backend](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/6622).

Comment: Thanks anyway for the reply, but I started that thread on GitHub. I ldidnt' delete this question  just to collect some other aswers.